# Unable to hide the nested div

Tags: jquery

This is my HTML Page .

I am trying to hide the **Topping-details** class present under **myordersdiv**

I was trying this way , but its not hiding  could anybody please help .

```
$("#myordersdiv .Topping-details").hide();


<div id="myordersdiv" style="display: block;">
   <ul>
      <li class="myorderhead active">
         <h5>
            My Orders
            <i class="myorderhead22">1</i>
         </h5>
      </li>
      <div id="ordersdiv">
         <div id="addtoordersdiv69">
            <div style="" class="Topping-details" id="69">
               <section id="topping_tsection_69">
                  <i id="topping-close"></i>
                  <aside>
                     <h6 class="tdHeading">Quantity      1</h6>
                     <img src="images/arrow-topping.png">
                     <section class="secclass"><a data-id="69" class="tpActive">Honey with Carmel  10 ML</a></section>
                     <section class="secclass"><a data-id="69" class="tpActive">Honey with Carmel  10 ML</a></section>
                  </aside>
               </section>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="confirmorder-row">
            <a id="ordersconfirm" hrer="#" class="btn btn-confirmorder">confirm order</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your code into DOM-Ready event

```
$(function(){
  $("#myordersdiv .Topping-details").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this -

```
$(function(){
    $("#myordersdiv .Topping-details").each(function(){
        var divId = $(this).attr('id'); // Here is your div id with class .Topping-details
        $("#"+divId).hide();
    });
});
```

Try this in [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/shailparas/Uk8gx/2/)

Comment: Can i have this under a single line??

Comment: Do u need all ids or single id?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion , I need to hide the Topping-details presetn under addtoordersdiv69 here

Comment: you mean something like that - `$("#myordersdiv #addtoordersdiv69 .Topping-details ").hide();`  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/shailparas/Uk8gx/6/)

Comment: 69 is dynamic it has got a variable id , how can i append that correctly

Comment: Look if you are using click event to hide then you can call a function by passing it that id and inside the function you achieve what u want like i have shown in my second demo. OR you if you want to hide multiple div  on a single click then you can also pass those ids. hope you are getting that what i'm trying to say.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57197/discussion-between-shail-paras-and-kiran).

Answer (score 0):

```
This seems to work.  




 <div id="myordersdiv">
<ul>
  <li class="myorderhead active">
     <h5>
        My Orders
        <i class="myorderhead22">1</i>
     </h5>
   </li>
  <div id="ordersdiv">
     <div id="addtoordersdiv69">
        <div style="" id="Toppings" id="69">
           <section id="topping_tsection_69">
              <i id="topping-close"></i>
              <aside>
                 <h6 class="tdHeading">Quantity      1</h6>
                 <img src="images/arrow-topping.png">
                 <section class="secclass"><a data-id="69" class="tpActive">Honey with                Carmel  10 ML</a></section>
                 <section class="secclass"><a data-id="69" class="tpActive">Honey with Carmel  10 ML</a></section>
              </aside>
           </section>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="confirmorder-row">
        <a id="ordersconfirm" hrer="#" class="btn btn-confirmorder">confirm order</a>
     </div>
  </div>
 </ul>
  </div>
```

$("#Toppings").hide();